# CakePHP disable button

Tags: php, cakephp, edit

I would like to know how I can create a function that, when a disable button is clicked for a record, it changes an active column's specific value to 0. it should be located under ['Album']['active'] which would by default be a 1. I tried

```
if ($id) { $this ->data[$id]['Album']['active'] = 0; 
     $this->Album->save($this->data);
```

Thanks

Comment: You should add code samples to your original post so that others can help you.

Comment: Provide some code sample so that peers can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this functions :

```
function active($id=null)
{

       $this->Album->id = $id;
        $this->data = $this->Album->read();
        if($this->data['Album']['active']==0)
        {
            $this->data['Album']['active'] = 1;
        }
        else            {
            $this->data['Album']['active'] = 0;
        }
        if($this->Album->save($this->data['Album']))
        {
            $this->redirect('/Controller/action');
        }

}
```